# How would I autowire a velocity template?

Tags: java, spring, velocity, autowired

I have a static velocity template that I need to use, so I was wondering if it is possible to autowire it instead of doing:

```
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("com/templates/template.vm");
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a FactoryBean that generates the velocity template as its result, and then the ApplicationContext will be able to autowire it into whatever beans need it. I can send you a sample if need be.